# Asp.net error object not set to a reference

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling

Because I rush in development (a lot of whip cracking here) and declare my objects at the top of the function and instantiate inside my try-catch block, I get a lot of the good old "object not set to an instance of an object" errors while doing TDD, and later if I do miss a branch that object was used in (doing VB now, would prefer C#) or just in every day coding,  object not set to an instance of an object is a bit vague. Sure the stack trace sends me to the line the error occured at, but it would be nice if I could modify my logging to either name the object or its type because sometimes I have multiple objects on the same line. It's not the end of the world, but in the end it would save me a few minutes each day. Any ideas on how I can pass the info on which object wasn't set? Thanks

Comment: By the way, this is VB.NET, not classic using try-catch-finally

Answer (score 1):

It is non trivial to "modify your logging" to output variable name or type - I am sure that if the framework could easily get this information from the executing IL, MS would have included it the null reference exception.

**Prevention is always better than cure.**  Here are a couple of tips I would do

### Fix your compiler warnings

C# would generate a compile error if it detects that there are code paths that could use an unassigned local variable.  [For some odd reason] VB.Net will still compile but the compiler will generate a warning - take heed of these and *go and fix the code* and you should never run into the problem of unassigned variables again!

**Adopt a different coding pattern for variable declaration**

I appreciate that method variable scope in ye olde VB was that the variable was visible throughout the entire method regardless of where it was defined.  As a result, it was a reasonable practice to put all your var declarations at the top of the method.  VB.Net of course is different - you can only use variables after they are declared and so it is OK (and I would say preferable*) to put the declaration (and assignment) closer to where the variable is actually used.  This should help you see "by eye" if your program logic means it is possible to use an unassigned variable.

- Some people think this is a think that it is always good practice to put variable declarations in a block at the top of the method.  I will not argue against them but I would say that that approach works best with small methods that do not use lots of variables.